# Передача пременной с javascript на PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Пытаюсь создать расширение для [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome). Этот скрипт должен записывать в переменную ссылку страницы на какой сейчас находится пользователь и отправлять её к файлу `index.php`. Проблемы возникли при передаче переменной с `javascript` на `PHP`. Переменная `$htmls` в `PHP` остается пуста.

Клиентская часть(script.js):

```js
    
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" // подключаем ajax
    var htmls =window.location.href; //узнаем на кой страныцы находится пользователь
    alert(htmls); // проверяем
      
    $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url : "index.php", // нужно ли здесь указывать полный путь к файлу?:E:\robstel\muk\php openServer\OSPanel\domains\mirror\index.php
 data: "htmls",
 })
```

Серверная часть(index.php):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
echo  $htmls; // проверяем принял ли PHP послание;
?>
</br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo  $htmls;` => `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @Let's say Pie  выскочило :  array(0) { } получаеться масив пустой? Но как же так если js выводит alert верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var htmls =window.location.href; //узнаем на кой страныцы находится пользователь

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "index.php",  // нужно ли здесь указывать полный путь к файлу?:E:\robstel\muk\php openServer\OSPanel\domains\mirror\index.php
    data: {url: htmls},
    })
```

Сервер

```
<?php
echo $_POST['url']; // проверяем принял ли PHP послание;
?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['url'])) { ... }`

Comment: @Let's say Pie то уже сам пусть додумывает :)

Comment: @Let's say Pie . Всё та же ошибка. А если поместить var_dump($_POST); в if (isset... то пустой екран.

Comment: @mokolotronmokolotron, а другие значения передаются через `ajax`?

Comment: @Let's say Pie . Проверил пример отправки формы с этого сайта: https://fructcode.com/ru/blog/how-to-send-html-form-with-ajax/  все работает. На крайний случый создам форму и запишу в нёе значение перемнной если ето возможно ).